# Google Play Store REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES Block

Tags: android, google-play

We have an app (version 11200) in the Google Play store that was recently removed from Google Play App Store.

We received this email notice from Google :

> #### Issue found: Permission use is not directly related to your app's core purpose.
>
> We found that your app (11200) is not compliant with how **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission is allowed to be used. Specifically, the use of the permission is not directly related to the core purpose of the app.
>
> **Additionally, follow these steps to bring your app into compliance:**
>
> Please remove the use of [REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://notifications.google.com/g/p/ACUgQrE9q4-ixytRKfvvhKFMWk6Io-foz-bswRpxVpXeZ3idOCz6-67hf5wew-UWXVkznpAH3uo_05T2G2SPoJl2dlyn8zvXasLpDWXp9ho13aGMMBgJXgM4SsFCNxOpMvV6tAU0b-2DmBNXFJEhhve9Ay_71Nx2NQRlxT9agKKGAIPF8dbOSluSmgocdMcz_xELvKk0UJSSmeeBjKtwHhxZ-oHWOengLzzyfwPn-TfO6dTfr9AOw_QlQZHlDmPxMAu-POoVEJuHIAOV) permission from all version codes within the submission. This includes both production and testing tracks.
>
> ..you **have to declare it in the App Content section of your app** before you can make a new release/update to your app.

So our app does  **not** need **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES**   and I am not sure why or how this security setting/flag was put into our app at the time when we built the app. So all in all, we do not want it in our app and we certainly cannot declare it in the App Content section as there is nothing to declare as it is not valid in our app.

**Our situation or problem then:**

What we are trying to do is create a new release (11300)  with REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES **removed and fully compliant,** but version 11200 is blocking us from creating a new release, due to the requirement for us to declare **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES,** but as mentioned we cannot declare it as it was added in error in previous releases.

When I spoke with Google, and they could not give tell me what I must do.

We now stuck in a blocked loop.

Anyone have any ideas or can assist me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB9wk.png) Screen dump of Declaration form.

We contacted Google but they could not give us any assistance. We tried creating new compliant release but we cannot save the release for review as the previous version is needing a declaration.

Comment: have you been able to resolve this ?

Comment: Ok so resolved this. Had to create a new build and complete the compliance form. Google Play then approved the new release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so resolved this. Had to create a new build and complete the compliance form. Google Play then approved the new release.